# Windows 11 Culture and UiCulture disagree

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, uwp

I'm writing a UWP app that supports localization. When testing on different machines I get opposite values for `Culture` and `UICulture`.

When both machines are set in Windows 11 to be `Español (Estados Unidos)` and have the Windows UI in Spanish, they returns swapped results:

- `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` returns `en-US` on one machine and `es-US` on another machine.
- `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` returns `es-US` on one machine and `en-US` on another machine.

This causes the localization not to work on the machine that returns `en-US` incorrectly for `CurrentUICulture` (i.e. it display the app in English instead of Spanish).

Interestingly enough, PowerShell returns the **opposite** values - `Get-Culture` returns the same value as `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` and `Get-UICulture` returns the same value as `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.

How can I get consistent behavior from Windows?

Comment: I have tested in Windows 11 environment, but I can't repro your problem, could you mind share your test environment info or share [mcve]?

Comment: That's the problem - I don't know what's the difference between the two Windows 11 machines. As for an MRE, just running `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` in LINQPad is enough to see the difference